# How can I write the difference between sysdate - due-date on trigger

Tags: sql, database, database-design, triggers, oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE penalty(
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    punishment_cost number(3),
    punishment_rate number(3),
    total_cost number(11)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_surname varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE,
    phone varchar2(11),
    mail varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    address varchar2(255),
    status number(1),
    role_id number(10) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE item(
    item_id varchar2(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_id number(11),
    publish_date DATE,
    is_occupied NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    publisher_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    category_name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    loan_id number(10)

);
```

```
CREATE TABLE current_loan(
    loan_id number(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE
);
```

Penalty is a week entity , but I want to ask how to find the difference between the system date and the return date of an item that a member has borrowed, and fill in the member _id field in the penalty(week entity) table and the member _id, total cost fields in the penalty table. total cost = penalty_rate * days, but this trigger's run condition should run when the return date exceeds the system date.
For example
member takes a book start date - return date : today - tomorrow , but after 2 days trigger will be inserted a new row in penalty table but ı cannot do it. because sysdate-tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

A trigger can only run when data is modified in the table. One way to approach this would be to use a view instead of a table to calculate the penalty at runtime instead of trying to store the static data. Also, your data model could use a little adjusting to make generating that info simpler. Consider this arrangement:

```
/* store all info about the member */
CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_surname varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE,
    phone varchar2(11),
    mail varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    address varchar2(255),
    status number(1),
    role_id number(10) NOT NULL
);

/* store all info about the item, including punishment rate */
CREATE TABLE item(
    item_id varchar2(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    publish_date DATE,
    publisher_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    category_name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    punishment_rate number(3)
);

/* a loan is a relationship between member and item, with dates */
CREATE TABLE current_loan(
    item_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL
    loan_date DATE NOT NULL,
    due_date DATE NOT NULL
);

/* calculate overdue fees for each member as of current sysdate */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW punishment AS
SELECT
    m.member_name,
    sum(i.punishment_rate*trunc(sysdate-l.due_date)) total_cost
FROM
    member m
    left join current_loan l on (l.member_id = m.member_id)
    left join item i on (i.item_id = l.item_id)
WHERE
    (sysdate - l.due_date) >= 1
GROUP BY m.member_name;
```

The view will show the total penalties for each member across all loans, based on the difference between current sysdate and due date, only for overdue returns. Because it is a view, the total amount is calculated at runtime and is always current. Alternatively, if you must store the actual total in a column, you could implement this as a materialized view that would refresh on a set schedule. This approach would only be recommended if you were performing so many calculations when querying the view that it affected performance of the query.

Note: You include a `member_password` column in your member table. not sure what you actually plan to store there, but storing the actual password for a user account is *always* a bad idea. At most you should only store a one way hash of the password, probably as a `RAW` data type.